# Background issue - extended

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a background issue.
The background is too extended. The image on this pen is 500 px wide, but originally i have an image that is larger, about 1500px? However the effect is the same as on pen.
No matter what the width the image is extended as it is on pen.

My codepen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

change the css you made like the following:

instead of:

```
background-size:cover;
```

to

```
background-size:contain;
```

the difference between the two is that 'cover' will scale your image as large as possible to cover the entire background, but most of the times when doing that the image will not fit in(most of the time the image is just larger).

when using 'contain' it will scale your image to the largest size when both the height and the width will fit into the background.

now, if your image is smaller than the page then it will repeat itself, unless you add :

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

i looked on your codepen link, and the image is too small, this is why when you will write the 'no-repeat' part it won't cover the entire background.

I suggest that you will find an image which is at least cover the height and the width of the background.